# Multiplying multiple specific areas in NetCDF file with constants

Tags: python, netcdf, climate-data-operators

I have wind speed NetCDF files for the UK (land and sea areas) I wanted to multiply a constant (say 1.5) by the wind variable for all land areas and a constant (say 2.4) for all sea areas. How can I do that, preferably in Python? If not in Python, what else could I use, as I have a lot of these .nc files and I will loop over them to apply the constants? An example of a .nc file is in the link.

https://www.dropbox.com/l/scl/AABKha2vlU90gbR25TgzVE9Wkq1kDvn1ntM

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Raster Subtraction using rasterio or gdal](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/394445/raster-subtraction-using-rasterio-or-gdal)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in python by opening the netcdf variables and making them numpy arrays. To multiply a constant by a numpy array from a netcdf is simple e.g. 1.5*array.

It depends on your data and how you can tell which cells are land and which water. Say cells above a threshold are land and below are water, you probably want to use something like an 'if' in loop to say multiple x by cells in the array that are below the threshold, and y by cells that are above the threshold.

To start off in python you want something like

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset #"onda install -c anaconda netcdf4"
import numpy as np

path = '/Users//Documents/AutoSeaIceProduc2/yourfule.nc'#Path to your  file
NETCDFdata = Dataset(path) #Open your netcdf
NETCDFdata.variables #look at your file
NETCDFdata.variables.keys #look at your file
lats = NETCDFdata.variables['latitude'][:] #these names comes from keys in your file
lons = NETCDFdata.variables['longitude'][:]
time = NETCDFdata.variables['time'][:]
wind = NETCDFdata.variables['winddata'][:,:,:]
```

e.g.

```
DoubleWind = 2*wind #This would multiple whole array for all time steps by 2.
```

Now you have the data in python as arrays to work with

```
myarray[myarray > 0.7] = 0 #this would make all the values above 0.7 = 0 if that approach helps you distinguish land/sea, for example
```