# Raster Subtraction using rasterio or gdal

Tags: python, raster, gdal, rasterio

I'm beginner to python. Each directory has two rasters named A.tiff and B.tiff. I need to subtract B.tiff from A.tiff and store the resultant file in the same directory. The directory paths are named by their date of creation(ex: /home/hash/images/20210121T123308/*A.tiff"). In a similar way I have directories created for each week from January with files A and B.
Below is my example code to fetch A and B's path

```
import glob
A_path = glob.glob("/home/hash/images/**/*A.tiff", recursive = True)
B_path= glob.glob(("/home/hash/images/**/*B.tiff", recursive = True)
```

Note: Both the file's metadata are same.

Comment: You should find this answer useful for doing it with gdal https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/285685/72647 
Once you have your A and B as arrays, it is simple as A-B for the calculation. This answer will show you how to open and save as tiffs that have projection info of original.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example: https://www.earthdatascience.org/courses/use-data-open-source-python/intro-raster-data-python/raster-data-processing/subtract-rasters-in-python/

If they have the same CRS/resolution/boundary:

```
import rioxarray
lidar_dem_xr = rxr.open_rasterio(lidar_dem_path, masked=True).squeeze()
lidar_dsm_xr = rxr.open_rasterio(lidar_dsm_path, masked=True).squeeze()
lidar_chm_xr = lidar_dsm_xr - lidar_dem_xr
lidar_chm_xr.rio.to_raster(output_path)
```

Otherwise, you may need to use `rio.reproject_match`: https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/reproject_match.html

If you use reproject match, you may need to use assign_coords to make the coordinates the exact same: https://github.com/corteva/rioxarray/issues/298#issuecomment-820559379

Here is an example of raster calculations using reproject match: https://carpentries-incubator.github.io/geospatial-python/07-raster-calculations/index.html

Comment: Hi , I have tried doing it but my kernel is getting restarted (dying ) always when it's trying to perform that calculation.

Comment: Are you able to run the calculation using python without a Jupiter notebook?

Comment: My raster files have zero values, willthat cause an issue?

Comment: That shouldn't cause an issue. How is your memory in the computer? Are the rasters large?

Comment: What is the size of your RAM (memory)?